# How to set height of div match its container

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is container. This div contain 2 div tags, as below:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container{
    height:100%
}

#child1{
    height:35px;
}

#child2{
    overlow-y:auto;
    height: ??? /**to match remain space of container**/
}
</style>


<div id="container">
    <div id="child1">this is a child1</div>
    <div id="child2">this is a child2</div>
</div>
```

How can I set child2's height to match remain space of container which is vertical scroll bar if child2's content is too much?

Comment: Fix the max-height of container same as its current height and child 2's height should be equal to containers height-35px

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't to fix height of container because it is dynamic value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a mix of relative and absolute positioning:

```
#container{
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}

#child1{
    height:35px;
}

#child2{
    overflow-y:auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 35px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

You don't actually set the height at all, you make the element `35px` from the top and `0px` from the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/AMQ8f/4/

Comment: Thanks James, if child2's content is too long, scroll bar will not appear. http://jsfiddle.net/AMQ8f/3/

Comment: @user532017 It works, you just had a typo in `overflow`.  http://jsfiddle.net/AMQ8f/4/

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have a new question. If child1's height is auto, how to set child's height to scroll bar appeared?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution would be to use `calc`:

```
#child2{
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 35px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AMQ8f/1/

IE9+  http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: Thanks James! Have you been the solution for IE7, 8? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the calculate function

```
      height: calc(100%-35px)
      height: -webkit-calc(100%-35px)
      height: -moz-calc(100%-35px)
```

I have never actually used this and probably not all browser will support this, but I though it could work.

Comment: calc is only working on ie9+ but I want to test on ie7,8. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there is an error or i think its a typo in your css `overlow-y`

create a function to adjust height of `child2` that will be called when the page loads and on the event which changes the height of the `container`

[**DEMO & CODE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/cQrHs/1/)

**NOTE:-** scroll the fiddle output there is a button below the container to change the height of container

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setHeight();

     $('#change').click(function () {
        $('#container').css('height', '300px');
        setHeight();
     });

});

function setHeight (){
    $('#child2').css('height', $('#container').height() - 35 + 'px');
    $('#child2').css('max-height', $(this).height())
}
```

Comment: Thanks UDB. This is a good solution. If browser was resized, the height was changed?

Comment: @user532017 [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/nJbwq/3/) will work in case of re-sizing the browser window you have to call `setHeight` on 'window resize event'. please **note** that the demonstaration is not working in *jsfiddle*  properly so copy and create your html file to see it working

Comment: Thanks for your instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, I assume you want it to scroll? if so

```
child2{
overlow-y:scroll;
height: 100%;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: If you set height 100%, content of child2 will to lost on the bottom.